# How to Compare Column in one Table to OneOther Value using SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to perform an analysis where I select from a table only rows that fulfill certain criteria. In this instance, I am interested in date criteria. Specifically, in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM INPUT_TABLE
WHERE THE_DATE<='2018-01-01' and THE_DATE >='2017-01-01'
```

I wish to replace the strings  `'2018-01-01'` and `'2017-01-01'`
with a sort of subquery, where I keep the values of the minimum and maximum dates in another table,called `VALUE_TABLES` which has the following 2 values:

```
MAX_DATE    MIN_DATE
2018-01-01   2017-01-01
```

How exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM INPUT_TABLE i JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(DATE) as MIN_DATE, MAX(DATE) as MAX_DATE
      FROM TABLE2
     ) t2
     ON i.THE_DATE >= T2.MIN_DATE AND i.THE_DATE <= t2.MAX_DATE;
```